# Google maps javascript api - Map not showing on print or print preview but shapes are

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, printing

I have a map that I have utilized shapes (pologons, lines, box...) that the user creates on the map.  Everything is working fine except for printing.  When I print the page from the browser all that shows for printing is the shapes.  The map itself is not showing nor is it showing up on preview.  Any ideas on why this is happening?  This happens on IE, Chrome, and Firefox.

The applciation is an ASP.Net mvc application.

Comment: there is no accepted answer here, but could be a browser issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611182/google-map-not-shown-when-printing

Comment: So all three browsers are having this issue?  No likely, but thanks for the reply.

Comment: Good luck with your issue.

Comment: Still haven't found a solution to why the map is not showing.  Where are all the Google developers the Google developer site says will provide feedback if I post here?

Comment: Discovered the issue is in Bootstrap.  I was able to get it to show once I added the following ccs: img {
        max-width: none !important;
    }

Answer (score 6):

Bootstrap is somehow breaking this...add the following code in your css sheet:

```
img { 
    max-width: none !important; 
}
```

Comment: What the .... why is this behaving like this and how you figured it out??

Comment: Bootstrap adds a lot of printing styles to the page. So if you are building the page, that is targeted for printing, be vary about this. Just to name some, backgrounds are set to transparent, font color is changed to black, etc.